# Is there a public view of the Tor network speed?

Tags: speed

Is there a way to see how fast Tor is publicly? A site with Tor stats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tor Project provides the [Tor Metrics](https://metrics.torproject.org/) website which allows you to see a variety of details about the network. You may find the [Performance](https://metrics.torproject.org/torperf.html) page useful.